Process Mining in SAP PP
I am trying to implement using Process Mining for SAP PP module using pm4py.
Before moving on to the algorithms, I need to process my data from SAP tables i.e.

CDHDR – Change Documents Header
CDPOS – Change Documents Item
AFKO – Production Order Header Data
AFPO – Production Order Item Data
AUFK – Order Master Data
T001W - Plants
USR02 – Logon Data

First I am trying out the tutorial to process the data by SAP in this link https://help.sap.com/doc/63369768645a4883b468546b2c122b23/3.19/en-US/Sample%20Content%20Process%20Mining%20on%20SAP%20S4HANA%20Production%20Planning.pdf#page=11&zoom=100,92,166
But I am not able to understand the derivation once my 'Header and Line Item Data' (Table AFKO, AFPO and AUFK) and 'Header and Line Item level Document Changes' (CDHDR, CDPOS).
I recreated the tables in my local RDBMS and tried to do the joins, and now I don't know how to proceed.
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM (AFKO AS ko
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AFPO AS po ON ko.AUFNR = po.AUFNR)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AUFK AS kf ON ko.AUFNR = kf.AUFNR
    ) AS af_data
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM cdhdr AS hc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cdpos AS lic ON hc.CHANGENR = lic.CHANGENR
    ) AS cd_data
ON af_data.AUFNR = cd_data.objectid 

